# How do we build jquery mobile UI

Tags: jquery-mobile

i'm totally a beginner of jquery mobile, i'm wondering how does everybody build the UI?
by html markup or writing pure code?

if it's by html markup, then if i have a complex applicaiton , then i'm gonna have a very long html file with a lot of pages, how do you deal with that?

if with pure code, i don't find it easy to create widgets, the only i found it just to put the pure html code into a jquery object wrapper. it's not very object-oreinted, i want some simple ways like: var $aButton = new button( );

i had ios native app development experience, normally i write the ui with pure coding. i'm just wondering if there's way to build ui with pure code?

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html

Comment: jQM is built with html markup; built-in widgets will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official way to build the UI in pure code but no one stops you from writing your own "code generator".

Be warned:
Writing HTML is the easier way to do, because JQM will do all of the UI-manip.

I'm working on a UI generator for JQM which 
will be released opensource. Still a lot to do but it already works more or less - see http://officejs.com

Check the **erp5loader.js** file which generates the whole app - there is only an empty index.html.

The factory section contains all methods necessary to generate JQM UI. The JSON files loaded show how to generate static and dynamic widgets as well as how to hook into navigation and global action bindings

Roll your own or wait until we are releasing ours :-)